# DocuSign integration using REST API - parameters for process initiator

Tags: docusignapi

via the DocuSign REST API we're **creating an envelope**. The creation is done via a background job from a different system and works fine, but I still would like to add an additional parameter.
And here I struggle. I would like to **hand over the original initiator of the process**, so that this person could find the envelope in his/her DocuSign Inbox.

Is this possible? I've tried *sender*, but this does not work or maybe I pass the wrong values?
Or would I have to use a different way, like shared envelopes?

I'm quite new to this topic, so a hint would be very kind. Thanks a lot.

I've tried to add the parameter sender, but I neither get an error nor the expected result.

```
 {

  "emailSubject":"envelope for integration",

  "status":"created",

  "compositetemplates":[
    {

      "compositetemplateid":"1",

      "servertemplates":"",

      "inlinetemplates":[],

    }

  ],

  "sender":[
    {

      "email":"myemail@test.de",

      "username":"Claudia",

      "userid":"b3r2fc59-g34d-256d-v364-23f34ere5f97",

    }

  ],

  }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please edit it. What do you mean by add a parameter? Add metadata? Add a field (tab)? Set the value of a tab? And what do you want by "hand over the original initiator"? The sender should see the envelope before it is sent? Or receive the envelope as a cc???

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [JWT](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/).
With JWT you impersonate any user in the account by providing their **userId** when you authenticate to get an access token.
You do need to [provide consent](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent/) by that user once, but after that - you can do this with your app automatically and the envelope will show as if it was created by the user you want.